# Java File.toURI() issue on Linux

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to get the URI of a File to put into a HTML document, which is then later processed to read the image locations (which are in the system temp directory) from that HTML and do some processing on the images.

It works fine on Windows, but on Linux I'm running into issues where the image locations from the HTML can't be found for subsequent processing. I think the issue is as follows...

On Windows, the File.toURI().toString() command is returning (for C:\temp\image.jpeg):

file:/C:/temp/image.jpeg

On Linux, it is therefore presumably returning (for /tmp/image.jpeg):

file://tmp/image.jpeg

This is being interpreted by the HTML parser as tmp/image.jpeg (i.e. a relative path), and therefore can't be found.

Is there an easy workaround for this, or do I need to manually force the URI to be correct (I guess file:///tmp/image.jpeg and file://C:/temp/image.jpeg)?

Comment: Don't publish `file:` URIs to HTML documents. Use relative URIs or absolute URIs with respect to the site's root instead. Google on the difference of relative and absolute URIs when it comes to publishing web sites for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing the following:

```
String imageUri = File.toUri().toString().replaceFirst("^file:/", "");
```

The regular expression should help you get the file resource on Windows as well as Linux

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment to your question: **Don't publish `file:` URIs to HTML documents.**

*Use relative URIs or absolute URIs with respect to the site's root instead*.

Google on the difference of relative and absolute URIs when it comes to publishing web sites for details.

**Now, if you are so bent over using file: URIs**, then you might want to try to get the canonical path. Hell, the canonical path is the preferred type of path one would want to use to publish file locations (except when publishing on the web as I mentioned before):

```
// java-like pseudocode:

String myFile = ... // some path, relative or absolute, to a file in an accessible file system

URI = (new File(myFile)).getCanonicalFile().toURI();
```

Check the Oracle/Sun javadoc information on File and getCanonicalFile/getCanonicalPath for details.

This might still not solve the issue since you are mentioning **the HTML parser** treats file: URIs as relative (but you do not mention what **HTML parser** you are using.)

At the end of the day, you will do better with publishing URLs relative to your documents' root instead of using `file:` URIs. Those URIs were never meant to be used like that.

Comment: The problem isn't the location of the file itself (and it's not being published, only used internally). It's that on Linux it is treating an absolute path as relative because it's interpreting the first slash of the file path as part of the protocol, thereby misinterpreting the path as relative.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving absolute paths, you need import the image to your project and then give to your code a relative path inside your project.